# Microsoft Graph Custom User Properties

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I followed instructions here: http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2016/03/08/office-365-working-with-new-delve-profile-page-top-features/ which allows me to add custom profile fields to MS Delve.

Is there anyway to access those created fields via the MS Graph api? I've tried everything I Can think of, including using the beta api, directly $select 'ing the data in the REST request, and can't seem to figure it out.

I've read a lot about extensions, but can't seem to get this data.

Comment: Are these schema extensions or open extensions. If they're open extensions, you can add `?$expand=extensions` to include them in the response of their associated resource

Comment: No idea which is part of why I'm stuck. I'm adding a new user property under the SharePoint Admin > User Profiles > Manage User Properties section, so these properties are being added via Sharepoint admin, not the graph itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a custom profile field in the SharePoint User Profile Database. Currently there is no MS Graph API for accessing a user profile in SharePoint. You could use the SharePoint Rest API for this.

Comment: Thanks. Thats where I was heading after a few more days of searching for this. Appreciate the response